# Unable to schedule sms message sending Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, telephonymanager, smsmanager

I'm working on an android app that needs to set a schedule of sms messages to be sent at some frequency. For whatever reason I can't seem to get the messages to start sending.

This is the Schedule class:

```
public class SmsAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
private int hour1, minute1, hour2, minute2, frequency;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String phoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int currentMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    if (currentHour >= hour1 && currentHour <= hour2 && currentMinute >= minute1 && currentMinute <= minute2) {
        String[] messages = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.messages);
        manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, messages[(int)(Math.random() * messages.length)], null, null);
    }
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, SmsAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * frequency, pi); //millisecond * second * minutes
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SmsAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}

}
```

I set all the private variables at the top of this class from my mainactivity and I also create a serialized object of this class that I can use to persist the alarm for each use.

In case I'm not using the right permissions I will post my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission> 
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone see why I would be unable to send messages?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing registering your receiver in Manifest file, With appropriate action string. as given below.

```
 <receiver android:name=".SmsAlarm" > 
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.android.whatever.WHAT_EVER_NAM_YOU_WANNA_GIVE" />
            </intent-filter>// can change name/action string as par ur requirement.
    </receiver>
```

and create a different .java file for your `BroadcastReceiver` class

you need to set same action string in your intent, Remember Action string must be same in Manifest and here intent.setAction("com.android.whatever.WHAT_EVER_NAM_YOU_WANNA_GIVE"); in java also. then only it will tringger receiver.

Your code can be changed like given below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), to_call_when_alarm_goes_off.class);
intent.setAction("com.android.whatever.WHAT_EVER_NAM_YOU_WANNA_GIVE");// added line

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarms.cancel(pIntent);


alarms.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        System.currentTimeMillis()+1000, 
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, 
        pIntent);
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you're saying to make the pending intent and the alarm global within the class, set the pendingintent to the receiver action from the manifest, and then create a whole separate file for the onReceive method?